# I messed up my samba and having problems reinstalling

Tags: samba

I upgraded my ubuntu from 13.04 to 14.04 and was having problems with sharing files over my windows network. In my wisdom I removed the samba and samba client

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge samba
sudo apt-get remove --purge smbclient libsmbclient
```

and also deleted the folder `/etc/samba/` and tried to do a fresh re-install with

```
sudo apt-get install samba 
sudo apt-get install smbclient libsmbclient
```

but now it won't recreate the `/etc/samba/` with the config files.
I did a search for samba in my file directory and there are numerous files but not the config files.

How can I clean up my system and do a fresh reinstall of samba?

Answer (score 0):

Check out `/usr/share/samba/smb.conf`. 
You'll need to recreate /etc/samba with `sudo mkdir /etc/samba`.